# How to add Agora.io Android sdk in expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, agora.io

I am setting up a new expo application and want a support in my application.

I want to know how to add the android sdk of `agora.io` into my expo project?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately both the iOS and Android SDKs for `agora.io` require editing of native code. As `Expo` abstracts native code away from you meaning the only way to access native code is to either create your project using `react-native init` or by ejecting your `Expo` project.

Looking at the docs for iOS you can see that it requires you to add the SDK either by using cocoa pods or by inserting it directly into you Xcode project file. https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/ios_audio?platform=iOS#add-the-agora-sdk-to-your-project

Similarly for Android you have to add the SDK inside the Android folder and make changes to the `build.gradle` files. 
https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/android_audio?platform=Android#add-the-agora-sdk-to-your-project

However you are in luck. There are a couple of wrappers around the SDKs that can be used with a full `react-native` project or an ejected `Expo` project.

https://github.com/AgoraIO/React-Native-SDK

https://github.com/syanbo/react-native-agora

Comment: so what does this module do then?.. react-native-agora

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is out of date now, Agora does offer expo support per the following documentation:

https://www.agora.io/en/blog/building-a-video-calling-app-using-the-agora-sdk-on-expo-react-native/

The above article mentions this, but it should be noted that you will not be able to use Expo Go to test video call functionality since it requires native modules for the microphone and camera. I can speak from first hand experience that I have been able to use Expo Go for other features in the app, just not the Agora portions.